# Proof that $n^2 \not\in \omega(2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I'm trying to prove that $n^2 \not\in \omega(2^n)$ and I have to do it from definition.

$f(n) \in \omega(g(n)) = \left\{f(n)| \forall c>0, c \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \ge n_o  (f(n) \ge c g(n)) \right\}$

So we're trying to prove that
$n^2 \ge c 2^n$.

Using limits I can prove that $\exists c, n^2 \not\ge c 2^n$
$$\frac{n^2}{2^n} \ge c$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 0$$

$$0 \ge c$$

However I am wondering is there a way to prove it without the us of limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that you're showing is actually stronger:
You've proved that $n^2 \in o(2^n)$ which is equivalent to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^2/2^n = 0$.

Since these asymptotic notions are defined in terms of limits, you'll most likely will be using limits (at least implicitly) for proving such statements.